# BigVideo.js not working

Tags: jquery, html, video, fullscreen

I'm sure I'm missing something here:

Trying to use bigvideo.js to create a fullscreen background video with a direct mp4 link from vimeo. Cannot work out why it's not working. I have loaded all the jquery plugins and libraries required but am met with a blank screen every time I load.

Trying to execute it on this page http://dev.searsdavies.co.uk/christmas/

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Merry Christmas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bigvideo.css" />
</head>


<body>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.2.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bigvideo.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            BV.show('https://player.vimeo.com/external/148621522.hd.mp4?s=30a2101d9b98333e354eda46ff4b7451054d03c5&profile_id=119');
        });
    </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined
bigvideo.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined
dev.searsdavies.co.uk/:45 Uncaught TypeError: $.BigVideo is not a function

Comment: BigVideo relies on jQuery UI, specifically the sliders, you've included `jquery-ui-i18n.js`, which is the language file for jQuery UI, not jQuery UI ?

Comment: Have linked the google hosted jquery UI now and still not working

Comment: Same errors in console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined(anonymous function) @ bigvideo.js:21(anonymous function) @ bigvideo.js:23
(index):29 Uncaught TypeError: $.BigVideo is not a function

Comment: Check network or resources tab in console. Are there any 404 errors? Are you positive your path to bigvideo.js is correct? `BigVideo not a function` can only mean that your js libraries are not loading.

Comment: The script appears in the resources section of the developer console, so I believe it is being called correctly

Comment: SOLVED: had to include a link to video.js too, this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation